# Incorrect Data Getting inserted to oda.Fill(dtExcelData) in C# while uploading .csv file for .xls xlsx format the same is working fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, csv

I am trying to upload .csv file from front end which is written in ASP.NET C# once the csv file is uploaded which contains only 1 column i.e Client_ID the data is getting inserted into the table in sql data base but the values are incorrect for Eg the Client_ID is A123456 but in the Table it is getting inserted as 123456 also after 25 Records the values are inserted as NULL even though the data is correct same issue is not happening for .xls xlsx format the same is working fine without any issue

Below are my code aspx.cs file

Code of

```
string conString = string.Empty;
string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileAdnan.PostedFile.FileName);

switch (extension)
{
    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
         conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
         break;

    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
         conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
         break;

    case ".csv": //csv 
         //conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CsvConstring"].ConnectionString;
         excelPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Files/");
         conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + excelPath + "; Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(,)'";
         break;
}

conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);

using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
    excel_con.Open();
    string ClientID = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + ClientID + "]", excel_con))
    {
        oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
    }

    excel_con.Close();

    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_ClientID", con);
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 180;

            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empTempTab", dtExcelData);

            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adpt.Fill(ds);

            con.Open();

            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            // Set the database table name
            // sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Cl_Dev";

            // [OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
            // sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Client_Id", "Client_Id");

            // con.Open();
            // sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
            // con.Close();

            // Added on 8th oct 2021//
            // SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("DisplaycountofclientID", con);
            // sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@cnt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label5.Text.Trim();

            string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Cl_Dev";

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
            SqlDataAdapter OleDbDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
            OleDbDa.Fill(dsData);

            con.Close();

            int recordcount = Convert.ToInt32(dsData.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString());
            Label5.Text = "Total" + "&nbsp;" + recordcount + "&nbsp;" + "records have been uploaded successfully";
    }
}
```

`Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="Excel03ConString"  
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
    <add name ="Excel07+ConString" 
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'"/>
    <add name ="CsvConstring"  
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Data in actual CSV file:

```
Client_Id
K1000010
K1000012
K1000012
K1000015
K1000013
K1000014
K1000011
K1000012
K1000018
K1000012
K1000017
K1000010
```

Data after getting inserted into table

```
1000010
1000012
1000012
1000015
1000013
Null
Null
Null
```

Comment: If you put a break point on `sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empTempTab", dtExcelData);` does `dtExcelData` have the correct data? Can you show us the proc `Insert_ClientID`. Does this work when called manually? Also you shouldn't need `adpt.Fill(ds);`

Comment: Sounds like "type guessing" is active in the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver. Second the breakpoint suggestion, I'd expect to see incorrect values in the DataTable.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gery yes when i put break point as u suggested incorrect data is getting inserted  SP CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_ClientID]    
    empTempTab empTempTabtype READONLY    
AS    
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
        
    truncate table  dbo.Cl_Dev  
       
    INSERT INTO  dbo.Cl_Dev(Client_Id) 
    SELECT Client_Id  
   FROM empTempTab    
        
          
END        Yes also when i insert the data manually the data from CSV is getting inserted with help of task- insert data via flat file source adpt.fill(ds) is required to insert the dat

Comment: Thanks for the reply Always Learning how to check if type guessing is active if any changes required let me know also when i put break point and check the incorrect sheet is getting taken